# Will a windows 10 system reset fix corrupted drivers?

Tags: windows-10, drivers, bsod, reset

I believe I have corrupted drivers since the only way to reach the windows login screen and login is by disabling driver signature enforcement.

I can't use safe mode, system restore fails, and `sfc /scannnow` fails to repair the corrupted files. `DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /Scanhealth` and restorehealth didn’t do anything either.

So my question is, will a system reset with the option to keep files fix the corrupted drivers?

I also upgraded my pc from windows 8.1 to windows 10, then installed the anniversary update. Will a reset keep windows 10 with the anniversary update?

Examples of corrupted drivers affecting other programs:

[image]

Comment: it SHOULD. Depends what exactly is corrupted. System reset is basically reinstalling windows and deleting all programs. Pretty sure that extends to drivers too then

Comment: Basically it is "reinstalling" your windows. Any 3rd party driver will be removed, and replaced with Microsoft generic driver. Afterward you can install the drivers, again. And I hope you mean "refresh", not reset.

Comment: @Vylix Author means Reset, Refresh would mean a fresh installation,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Essentially yes.

As described [here](https://www.howtogeek.com/132428/everything-you-need-to-know-about-refreshing-and-resetting-your-windows-8-pc/), what a system reset does is restore a Windows installation to factory default:

> Windows 10 includes a “Reset your PC” option that quickly restores
>   Windows to its factory default configuration. It’s faster and more
>   convenient than reinstalling Windows from scratch or using your
>   manufacturer’s recovery partition.

**How Resetting Your PC Works**

When you use the “Reset this PC” feature in Windows, Windows resets itself to its factory default state. If you purchased a PC and it came with Windows 10 installed, your PC will be in the same state you received it in. All the **manufacturer installed software and drivers that came with the PC will be reinstalled**. If you installed Windows 10 yourself, it will be a fresh Windows 10 system without any additional software.

You can choose whether you want to **keep** your personal files or erase them. However, all your installed programs and settings will be erased. This ensures you have a fresh system. Any problems caused by third-party software, system file corruption, system settings changes, or malware should be fixed by resetting your PC.

Windows reset will put the software back into the same condition as it was when you started it for the very first time (such as when you purchased the PC).

The process of PC resetting has been [explained](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/b8/2012/01/04/refresh-and-reset-your-pc/):

> Resetting your Windows 8 PC goes like this:
>
> 1. The PC boots into the Windows Recovery Environment (Windows RE).
> 2. Windows RE erases and formats the hard drive partitions on which Windows and personal data reside.
> 3. Windows RE installs a fresh copy of Windows.
> 4. The PC restarts into the newly installed copy of Windows.

In these instances it is evident that the process even takes care of odd drivers, replacing with factory configured settings and software and may help rid of unwanted drivers.

**Some important things worth noting**:

- Reset option resets to **default or original** installation i.e if the factory installed OS was Windows 8, after reset that what you get to use, (perhaps this may be overcome by using a specific OS disk - but I am not 100% sure)
- Windows 10 uses driver signature enforcement, so the drivers must be signed and certified with a  Microsoft compliant signatures, otherwise the drivers won't load.